# How to test Smart App Banner Urls on in Dev environment

Tags: ios, ios6, meta-tags

I'm wondering if it's possible to test iOS 6's smart app banners' app-argument URL parameter on dev builds of an iOS app.  It appears the Open option in the banner only appears if the application is downloaded from the App Store.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What worked for me was to download my application from the appstore, and then overwrite it using a build from XCode.  This worked and allowed me to debug the smart banner feature using my current build.  This won't work from the simulator, you need to use a device.

Just to be clear, you must overwrite it.  You can't delete the appstore version, and then build from XCode.

Comment: Works for me, however appDelegate method openUrl is not called. I don't know why..

Comment: @OdedRegev  have you fixed it ??

Comment: It does not seem to work anymore on Xcode 6. Is there another way?

Comment: @KevinHirsch any luck? Trying to test here as well. I have deep-linking working with a JS window.open redirect as well as typing it directly in browser, but smart banners won't work...

Comment: Does not work on Xcode 7. How can I test the app-argument parameter?

Comment: Somebody know how can I do in dev mode?, my app isn't published yet

Comment: As of March 2024 this solution does not work

Answer (score 2):

As of now, Xcode 8 and iOS 10, I have tried all the methods but **Cannot Debug** the smart banners URL that is being opened, as it needs the store versions of the application.

I have found a workaround of this, and have tested my application using this.

Apart from the `<meta ...>` tag I have also added a link button on the page that uses the scheme to open the app.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxxx,pt=xxxxx,ct=xxxxx,app-argument=myappscheme://www.mymobilesite.com/link/detailpage?query=x">
    <title>Banner Debug Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Visit <a href="myappscheme://www.mymobilesite.com/link/detailpage?query=x">App Using Scheme</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this link I can debug the Dev builds and works well.

Though this only works when the app has registered a scheme for itself, but just for testing we can register a dummy scheme say `appscheme://` and replace `http://` scheme with dummy scheme, test it, and then revert links from app `scheme://` to `http://`

Comment: Hi @ BangOperator  , My app is already available on App Store , And now i want this functionality in my app and so its not possible to debug it as you have mentioned in your article. I have added URL scheme into application’s plist file and browse that URL in safari and I am able to open the app and also able to fired the “openURL” method. BUT in Apple Doc they told us to handle the Smart App Banners with “sourceApplication annotation” method .

Comment: @ BangOperator  So while pushing this new feature to the App Store Do we need to change the logic that applied into “openURL” TO “sourceApplication annotation” ? And so while my app will be live with this new feature , Smart App Banners will be handled through “sourceApplication annotation” ? I guess i also need to remove the URL scheme which has been added for testing purpose ?

Comment: @GOPALVASANI Check https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/ios-smart-banners-ba0a81b0d23a

Comment: @ BangOperator , hahahaha i already read that article and you can found my comment there . Anyway it is a very nice article and the author also replied me quick . And thanks for your reply as well .

Answer (score 1):

This is a hassle, but what we did is add some logging messages and submit the build for Apple review marked for manual release.  When the app is approved, issue a promo code for the unreleased version.  Redeem the promo and that will install the unreleased version of the app.  Go to safari and hit your web page with the meta tags to display Smart App Banners.  Should launch your app and pass the URL.  Then look at the console for your log messages.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me using an iOS 6 device, because it didn't work with iOS 8.

I installed the app from the AppStore and then overwrite it with a dev build using Xcode 6.