# iOS 9 smart app banners not coming back

Tags: html, ios, web, ios9

I'm having an issue with smart app banners disappearing on iOS 9. Once they are dismissed/closed, I'm not able to bring them back on any of my next visits. I'm not sure if this is also an issue is iOS8.

Once a user dismisses the banner, how do I get the banner to come back?

I've tried clearing all website data, resetting settings, etc. But the banner wont come back. I've followed the steps in this tutorial, but it only covers up to iOS7.1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/80347/smart-app-banners-tutorial

**Steps to reproduce:**

- On your iphone, visit math-ninja-app.com
- dismiss the app banner
- revisit the page, banner is gone
- clear all website data in safari settings, and revisit page.
- banner is still gone.

How do I get it to come back? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I only have a little bit of experience with this, but from what I understand, once the user dismisses it, iOS/the users' device stores a flag for that site that's independent of Safari. It's up to Apple's own code for when it comes back, if at all.

Comment: check reset instructions here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21443525/1403732

Comment: Some update for you man?. I have problem testing in dev app, my app is in dev mode, I don't know how can I test. I was trying do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15287524/4483716 but It doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart app banners do not appear after being closed on iPad with IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412838/smart-app-banners-do-not-appear-after-being-closed-on-ipad-with-ios7)

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I found in iOS 9 is really hard to me is reset and erase all content of my device.

Settings -> General -> Reset -> **Erase All Content and Settings**

**Note:**

Be very careful, this is going to delete all from your device.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's documentation ("[Promoting Apps With App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)") clearly says;

> And with a large and prominent close button, a banner is easy for users to dismiss. When the user returns to the webpage, the banner won’t reappear.

So if settings reset or clearing cache didn't bring back the banner, maybe you should take a backup before closing that banner and restore if you need it back for some reason.