# Is it possible to download an app from appstore from a link and open it directly through the same click?

Tags: ios, app-store, uiapplication

In one of my current iOS projects, I need to have a functionality like, when we click on a link our app should get downloaded from appstore and automatically get active and when opens it, we should save some parameters which were present in the url. Is that something achievable in iOS?

Comment: This can't be done. There is no way to pass data to a newly installed app. And there is no way to automatically launch a newly installed app.

Comment: Is there a way to set parameters in Appstore url?

Comment: Since the App Store URL already has lots of parameters, then yes. Of course if you add your own, they may cause problems and they certainly won't be of any use. They won't be sent to the app.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260456/does-itunes-pass-referral-parameters-on-iphone-once-app-is-installed

Comment: @cherukkayi From your app you can only open the application app store page, but it will never automatically download from app store. User needs to 'Install' it explicitly. Once that app is installed, you can open it from your app and pass few parameters. For this, that app must support custom url and should interpret the parameters passed in the url.

Comment: @Amar Can you please tell me how to pass values to my app for the first time? My objective is to download my app from a url with unique values. it should pass the value to the app store app page, and once the user has installed, then he should receive the value on the app launch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in 1 click, once the App is installed, the user will have to click the "Open" button.