# Does app-argument on Apple Smart Banner get passed to app on install?

Tags: ios

I've implemented a Apple Smart Banner for my app, including a app-argument with a URL I'd like the app to open on my site. I thought that would pass through when the user installs the app, but it doesn't seem to.

The steps - user visits page, doesn't have app installed, clicks View, goes to app store, installs app and then taps Open in the App Store. The app opens, but it doesn't appear to get the app-argument passed in. Note that if they then go back to the web page, the Smart Banner now says Open and that works and passes the app-argument, just not on the first install.

Have I misunderstood what is supposed to happen? If so, this makes the Smart Banner pretty much useless for me.

Gary

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, Gary?

Comment: Looks like this is an iOS bug :-/ Doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 12):

From the docs:

> If the app is already installed on a user's device, the banner intelligently changes its action, and tapping the banner will simply open the app. If the user doesn’t have your app on his device, tapping on the banner will take him to the app’s entry in the App Store. When he returns to your website, a progress bar appears in the banner, indicating how much longer the download will take to complete. When the app finishes downloading, the View button changes to an Open button, and tapping the banner will open the app while preserving the user’s context from your website.

It only sends the URL param if the app is opened via the banner. If it's opened via AppStore or via SpringBoard, it won't send it.

Comment: @StéphanePéchard, Thats fine for me, I never wait for the store the finish the download and use its open button to open the app. I rather switch back to what I was doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with [branch.io](http://branch.io). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053042/1034126).

**tl;dr**

What Branch does is generate a custom URL specific for your device and uses the same unique configuration to fetch the data when the application is opened. Thus, you need to include their SDK into your app in order to get those arguments you want to send.

Comment: More on the universal banner: https://branch.io/blog/2014/10/25/Introducing-the-first-universal-app-open-banner-with-deep-linking-past-install/

Comment: Does this work even if the user opens the app from AppStore, or only if the user goes back to Safari after install?

Comment: @Nilzor this works if the user goes to the AppStore through the Branch link. After that you'll receive the parameter in the app, no matter how it's been opened.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bug?

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

> When the app finishes downloading, the View button changes to an Open button, and tapping the banner will open the app while preserving the user’s context from your website.

Comment: As the OP said, tapping the Open button in the smart banner itself does pass the app-argument; just not when it's opened in other ways after install.