# Is it possible to track the sender if a sender's request refers to the app, that has not been installed yet

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, url-scheme

My target is to invite friends to the app. The key point is to be aware of who sends the request for a certain user. There is no problem, if you invite someone who has an installed application. In such case you can use scheme URL and handle it properly via

- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

But what to do, if the user has not the necessary app. Is it possible to implement a such workflow:

"Invitation link" -> "Open appStore" -> "Download app" -> "Open app and elicit the sender's ID(or name)" -> ???

Maybe there is an another way how to do this. But my scenario implies invitation to the user's group. User sends request to his friend (Facebook,twitter etc.). But what to do, if his friend will sign up using not a Facebook account that you expect, but for instance his email address or twitter account or something else.

In such case, I can't define, that this new user should be invited to the right group.

Sure, it is a possible way to include a notification in invitation message where you can ask the user to install the app before he will accept the invitation. But it seems to complex for user experience.

How can I solve this problem?

In other words:

If I build a deeplink to my app and send it to the user (to his email),  but for some reason he would not have an installed app.

In such case I'd like to redirect user to AppStore and after he downloads the app, handle a previously sent request in method:
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using a third-party service called [Branch](http://branch.io). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035004/does-app-argument-on-apple-smart-banner-get-passed-to-app-on-install/27100890#27100890).