# How to track the install referrer in ios

Tags: ios, google-analytics, referrer

I am doing one application.In that i want to implement one feature like as android.In android we can get the number of downloads by using install referrer.So in ios how can we do that install referrer.

Comment: Use this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260456/does-itunes-pass-referral-parameters-on-iphone-once-app-is-installed/26604302#26604302

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this (you should clarify this with your customers if this is ok for them) is to send data to your `server`. Just keep track of the session count (or even put a single value to your `NSUserDefaults`) and application version and you should be fine:

**Install:** session count is 0, send a `"hello"` message to your `server` (server stores `device ID`)

**Reinstall:** same as "`Install`" (server recognizes that the device id already exists)

**Update:** `application version` is not the same as on last startup, send a "`update`" message to your server