# iOS- Get referral code from appstore if app is installed from an ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics-firebase

I am not able to find a way in order to recieve referral code from the Google Conversion Tracking. What are the steps that need to be followed? It is simpler in android, while I couldnt find a direct way to implement it in iOS.

In case of Android play store link look like this: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=&referrer=guid%3D%guid%

As you can see referrer parameter at the end of url. Once app is installed in device then play store will send this parameter to app using INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast receiver. We can use this parameter.

Comment: Use this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260456/does-itunes-pass-referral-parameters-on-iphone-once-app-is-installed/26604302#26604302