# Does app-argument to iOS application get passed to app on install from App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have developed an application and now want to use it like when the user will install the app there should be some parameter to tell that from which place user got the Application URL, like the one in Android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=itcurves.mars.regency&referrer=newyourktimes

where referrer tells that application linked is opened from newyouktimes.

I want the application to be install from App Store with some additional parameter on downloading link to indicate referrer. I googled a lot and find that there is some app-argument through which we can achieve this goal but could not find its implementation or some example.

Please give some example to get parameter within the application when user downloads application from App Store.

How can I achieve this . to send parameter to app while installation from App Store?

Comment: Use this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260456/does-itunes-pass-referral-parameters-on-iphone-once-app-is-installed/26604302#26604302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not provided by the Apple App Store

Comment: No, I don't think there is any facility for this in the app store install process.

Answer (score 0):

Google Adwords has a library that can be used to do conversion tracking.
https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/docs/ios/using-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Apple added support for `app-arguments` to their Smart Banners.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) but the gist of it is that your referrer can be one of the app-arguments.