# How to obtain gclid (google click id) and fbclid (facebook click id) after app first installation on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-analytics, app-store

I'm trying to configure firebase (google) analytics and I need to obtain the user's ad click id in order to make conversions work correctly. How can I obtain click id after app first installation inside the app or via firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a feature from the app-store.

The best thing you could do is using some kind of fingerprinting, have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260456/does-itunes-pass-referral-parameters-on-iphone-once-app-is-installed) post.

Take a look at the [smart banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) `app-argument`, but I don't think this is available for first installs and limited to users installing the app from a smart-banner.

Comment: The SO post you referred is really old (2012), maybe there were AppStore updates in the past several years?

Comment: Yes, that might be true, but I'm not aware of any changes regarding this. As I mentioned the smart banner might be an option. Also branch.io is mentioned in the SO post and is still in business...